.Net MAUI mimic a Combo Box
I'm still trying to learn .Net Maui and I want to use the equivalent of a combobox.  I found this on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnKkUtBK23A that shows one way of making a combobox using Expander.  The video was probably made for dotnet 6 and I'm using dotnet 8 so I have had to make some changes. I'm also using VS 17.10.4 on Windows 11. The basic idea is to have a list of items in an Expander.  When the Expander is clicked, the list displays.  Then, when an item is clicked, the item is supposed to show in the header and the list closes.  This can then be repeated any number of times.  My code works in so far as the item click is detected (message displays he selected item in DebugView) but the header label doesn't update and the list remains open.  I've checked my code but I still can't work out why the bindings aren't working. Here is my code:
MauiProgram.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Combox
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}

MainViewModel.cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace Combox.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainViewModel : BindableObject
    {
        string _selectedText = "Select the item";
        public string SelectedText
        {
            get { return _selectedText; }
            private set { _selectedText = value; }
        }

        bool _isOpened;
        public bool IsOpened
        {
            get { return _isOpened; }
            private set { _isOpened = value; }
        }

        ObservableCollection<string>? _dataList;
        public ObservableCollection<string>? DataList
        {
            get { return _dataList; }
            private set { _dataList = value; }
        }

        public ICommand SelectionCommand { private set; get; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            DataList = new ObservableCollection<string>()!;
            DataList.Add("Item1");
            DataList.Add("Item2");
            DataList.Add("Item3");
            DataList.Add("Item4");
            DataList.Add("Item5");

            SelectionCommand = new Command(
                 execute: () =>
                 {
                     IsOpened = false;
                     Debug.Write($"SelectedText {SelectedText}");
                     RefreshCanExecute();
                 },
                 canExecute: () =>
                 {
                     return !IsOpened;
                 });


        }
        void RefreshCanExecute()
        {
            ((Command)SelectionCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
        }

    }
}

MainPage.xaml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
    
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Combox.ViewModels"
             x:Class="Combox.MainPage"
             x:Name="mainView">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                HeightRequest="185"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to &#10;.NET Multi-platform App UI"
                Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I" />

            <toolkit:Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsOpened}" HeightRequest="190">
                <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout MaximumHeightRequest="42" Padding="10">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding SelectedText}" />
                        <Label Text="&#9660;" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" HeightRequest="190" SelectionMode="Single"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedText}" 
                                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionCommand}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Text="{Binding}">
                            </Label>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </toolkit:Expander>

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me" 
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

Edit
Finally solved the problem.  The Binding issues were resolved by using SetProperty from the MVVM Community Toolkit.  The list not collapsing was due to a missing canExecute action in the command.  The final version of MainViewModel.cs looks like this:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace Combox.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        string _selectedText = "Select the item";
        public string SelectedText
        {
            get { return _selectedText; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedText, value); }
        }

        bool _isOpened = false;
        public bool IsOpened
        {
            get { return _isOpened; }
            private set { SetProperty(ref _isOpened, value); }
        }

        ObservableCollection<string>? _dataList;
        public ObservableCollection<string>? DataList
        {
            get { return _dataList; }
            private set { _dataList = value; }
        }

        public ICommand SelectionCommand { private set; get; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            DataList = new ObservableCollection<string>()!;
            DataList.Add("Item1");
            DataList.Add("Item2");
            DataList.Add("Item3");
            DataList.Add("Item4");
            DataList.Add("Item5");

            SelectionCommand = new Command(
                 execute: () =>
                 {
                     IsOpened = false;
                     RefreshCanExecutes();
                 },
                 canExecute: () =>
                 {
                     IsOpened = true;
                     return true;
                 });


        }
        void RefreshCanExecutes()
        {
            ((Command)SelectionCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
        }

    }
}


You can try https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls, which I have created an AutoCompleteView that does exactly this

Did Debug.Write($"SelectedText {SelectedText}"); output right value? In addition, I didn't see where did you update the SelectedText value when the item is selected.

The Debug.Write does output the correct value.  SelectedText is updated by SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedText}" when an item is selected.

I think the control you're looking for in Maui is the picker
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker?view=net-maui-8.0
According to official documentation:
The .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) Picker displays a short list of items, from which the user can select an item.


As for why your current code doesn't respect the bindings to write to the header and change the expander opening, I can assume (although I'm not sure since I haven't worked with .net in a while) that you need to call OnPropertyChanged(nameof(YOUR_PROPERTY_HERE)) each time you modify a value that changes the interface.
Something like:
    bool _isOpened;
    public bool IsOpened
    {
        get { return _isOpened; }
        private set {
_isOpened = value;
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOpened));
    }
        }


Although my test only has a few items, the app I'm hoping to develop will need a combo box of several hundred items, and I don't think that Picker is designed to handle that many.

I've made some progress by using the Community Toolkit MVVM.  This enables me to use SetProperty to update the _selectedText and _isOpened properties, so the chosen item appears in the expander header.  However the expanded section doesn't collapse when IsOpened is put to false.

See the question Edit to see how I solved this.  The Expander XAML and MainViewModel code could be used in any app that needs a simple Combo Box.
